# Accessing Gallery using ActivityResultContracts.GetContent

Tags: android

I have been following this tutorial to access the gallery using using ActivityResultContracts.GetContent.

[https://medium.com/codex/how-to-use-the-android-activity-result-api-for-selecting-and-taking-images-5dbcc3e6324b](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5b1X.png)

It asks me to create a new folder XML in the values directory and add a file called provider_paths.xml but I can't get beyond this point.
The manifest can't find the resource.
[image]

Comment: Create the xml folder under res/ not in res/values/ and it should work.

Comment: Thank you @Malik Saifullah this was the problem

Answer (score 0):

It might be an Android Studio bug. Did you try to close and reopen Android Studio?